# installing packages inside of new package Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am currently creating a package that also requires other packages to properly work. I have my package created with no issues. However, I am at the point where I am requiring another package to put inside my current created package. However, I am having issues doing this. I am not sure exactly how to do this. Do I just put the require file inside the composer.json and install it in my package like I currently have? Well I did that and it did install inside my package but I am not able to use it in the same regards as installing it in the root of a Laravel project.

Any advice for installing packages inside of packages would be great!

Comment: Well, as per your question I request you to see any of the packages made for Laravel by GrahamCampbell or by Thujohn

Comment: Adding the required package in composer is enough. It will be create a `vender` folder inside of your custom package

Answer (score 0):

go to the directory of custom package upto one step before the src and run following command

```
composer require --package name
```